# How to load an image from a file in c# in the UWP format

Tags: c#, image, uwp, slideshow

I'm a former IT professional, did a lot of database programming with all kinds of software, fiddle with all kind of programming languages, from PL/1 and Pascal to the latest Python. I'm trying to learn c# in the UWP environment, with a view to maybe write some Mixed Reality app. Yes I know I'm ambitious.... because right now it ain't working at all! lol!

I've given myself a little "simple" project to start fiddling with the classes and learn the software. It's a simple slideshow software in c# using the .Net framework because I want to be able to use it in Mixed Reality as well as a 2D app. I've already programmed this in Python so I'm trying to port it to c# (I know it's not a direct port... omg...). And god, I can't find any decent tutorial or piece of codes in the tons of google search I've done. Lots of it in c# without .Net, lots of it in other languages, but not in the environment I'm trying to use.

So! I've gone as far as creating my app in Visual Studio 2017, with a blank UWP app. I'm using a "Image" from the toolbox and put it on my screen, created a AppBarButton to put my controls into. I have created (using other example) a picker that return a Storage File to select a jpg file and am able to put the name in a textbox I created on the same screen.

However!!!

After hours of fiddling, I can't find how to load an image in this "Image" I created in XAML. Furthermore, I will want to manipulate this image, zoom it, rotate it, and I have no idea where to look. Finally if anyone could give me pointers as how to read a whole list of files from a directory and how to use Zip files as well, while we are at it, it would be much appreciated.

If you have pieces of codes, I'll read through it, or if you have tutorials I should do, please suggest away!!! However, being an experienced IT guy, I am looking for instructions that are to the point. I have tried looking at the Microsoft C# tutorial and lost patience over the tacky jokes and slow pace.... and I am a VERY patient guy in life....

For referenced, I have included here my XAML and C# code of where I am at right now. It is very frustrating to feel like a kid learning to speak after all these years of programming! lol!

The XAML piece:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <Grid/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
        <AppBarButton Icon="OpenFile" Label="AppBarButton" Tapped="Loadmedia"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Next" Label="AppBarButton"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="outtext" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="73" Width="1343" Margin="315,0,0,10"/>
    <Image x:Name="mypic" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="765" Margin="48,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1783" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="Black"/>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

And this is the C# code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Loadmedia(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        Image img = sender as Image;

        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

        StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        outtext.Text = file.Path;

        mypic.UriSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));



    }

}
```

Comment: Try to use mypic.Source instead of mypic.UriSource

Comment: Thanks Olman, I tried this also. What I have found so far is that you cannot load any picture from your computer, it has to be part of the resources of the app. I successfully loaded pics that were part of the resources..... I probably need another object than Image... Canvas? I don't know...….

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the BitmapImage's source with SetSourceAsync and the stream opened from the StorageFile rather than using just the StorageFile's Path. The app doesn't have permission to directly access the Path and needs to go through the file broker via the StorageFile.

There is a sample code snippet in the [BitmapSource.SetSourceAsync documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsourceasync#examples) which looks essentially like this once modded to your variable names:

```
// Ensure the stream is disposed once the image is loaded
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
{
     // Set the image source to the selected bitmap
     BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
     // Decode pixel sizes are optional
     // It's generally a good optimisation to decode to match the size you'll display
     bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = decodePixelHeight;
     bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = decodePixelWidth;

     await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
     mypic.Source = bitmapImage;
}
```

Check out the [Simple Imaging sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleImaging) and the [Basic input sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicInput) for examples of rotating, zooming, etc.

Comment: I'm really not sure of what I'm doing, but it's working! Will post code tomorow. Thanks so much Rob. Will look at this in detail to understand it!

Comment: The only piece that does not work is the "decodePixelHeight". I'm getting "does not exist in the current context".

Changed it to "(int) myimg.Height" instead... in this example "decodePixelHeight" needs to be the actual Image object height, am I correct?

Comment: Right. Define that to whatever is appropriate for your app or remove that code if you need the image at full size. The basic concept is that you don't want to open a high resolution image at full size if you're just going to display a thumbnail -- that will use a huge amount of memory for no purpose. You can tell the decoder a smaller size and it will scale it down when it reads in. If your app is a photo editor then you may want to load the photo-to-edit at full size even if it won't all fit on screen at once. More complicated schemes may be needed to manage very large images.

Comment: Thanks so much Rob! Now another twist for you. My image don't display with the right color profile.... They come up all greenisn because I'm using Photoshop to edit them.... Any way to change this?

Comment: You should be able to. I'd create a new question with details of the new issue